# Rails: Run a method when user left the edit view through the browser back button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a possibility to detect if a user has exited the edit view (edit action) without saving through the back button of the browser and then run a method to set the value of a field in the database? I tried after_action on the edit action but this fires directly after rendering the edit view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hitting the back button in a web browser won't involve Rails, but rendering the component to which it is being sent will.

You can save the data of the input fields in the browser's local storage or cookies and then have a before_action: in the controller they were sent to with the back button that looks for the presence of such value. 
( This solution involves some javascript )

Then, you can query accordingly to determine if those values should be saved in the database.

Note: If you need to cover not only the back button scenario, but also any other controller to which the user might navigate to in your app, you may add the before_action to somewhere else, like application_controller.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do. Also I need to cover the scenario where the user navigate through the app pages. Do you have any sample project/code for this, so I can have a look at how others solve this issue?